# monitor of systemd resource with pacemaker & corosync returns "not running" when cloned while it is

Tags: cluster, exim, failover, pacemaker, corosync

The setup:
- OS: CentOS 7, latest versions op Corosync, Pacemaker & PCS
- two node active/active cluster with a virtual IP
- on both nodes Exim is running for outoging mail (SMTP), nothing special in the config
- when Exim fails on one of the nodes, the node should no longer participate in replying to the virtual IP until Exim is back up and running

How I tried to get this working:
- cloned ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 resource for the virtual IP
- cloned systemd:exim resource to watch Exim with on-fail="standby" option

The problem:
Initially, everything is working as it should. When one of the nodes fails to run Exim, it stops correctly and the node no longer participates in the virtual IP. The problem is that somehow, after stopping and starting one of the nodes, Exim is restarted (as it should) but the monitor is returning "not running". When the Exim-resource isn't configured with on-fail="standby", everything works as designed and I can start/stop Exim and one of the nodes as much as I want.

Message in the log:

```
Jan 28 16:17:30 testvm101 crmd[14183]: notice: process_lrm_event: LRM operation exim:0_monitor_30000 (call=141, rc=7, cib-update=211, confirmed=false) not running
Jan 28 16:17:30 testvm101 crmd[14183]: warning: status_from_rc: Action 20 (exim:0_monitor_30000) on testvm101 failed (target: 0 vs. rc: 7): Error
Jan 28 16:17:30 testvm101 crmd[14183]: warning: update_failcount: Updating failcount for exim:0 on testvm101 after failed monitor: rc=7 (update=value++, time=1422458250)
```

Output of pcs status:

```
[root@testvm101 ~]# pcs status
Cluster name: smtp_cluster
Last updated: Wed Jan 28 16:31:44 2015
Last change: Wed Jan 28 16:17:13 2015 via cibadmin on testvm101
Stack: corosync
Current DC: testvm101 (1) - partition with quorum
Version: 1.1.10-32.el7_0.1-368c726
2 Nodes configured
4 Resources configured


Node testvm101 (1): standby (on-fail)
Online: [ testvm102 ]

Full list of resources:

 Clone Set: virtual_ip-clone [virtual_ip] (unique)
     virtual_ip:0       (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started testvm102
     virtual_ip:1       (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started testvm102
 Clone Set: exim-clone [exim] (unique)
     exim:0     (systemd:exim): Started testvm102
     exim:1     (systemd:exim): Started testvm102

Failed actions:
    exim:0_monitor_30000 on testvm101 'not running' (7): call=141, status=complete, last-rc-change='Wed Jan 28 16:17:30 2015', queued=6ms, exec=15002ms
```

As far as I can see, at the time of the message, Exim is running and working for systemd.
I already tried to specify the start-delay option, hoping that would make a difference (but it doesn't).

When running: `pcs resource cleanup exim-clone` to clear the fail count, everything works until the monitor-action comes up the first time, then the node that is marked as standby get switched by the other...

Example:
Status after the monitor of Exim failed on node testvm102:

```
[root@testvm101 ~]# pcs status
...
Node testvm102 (2): standby (on-fail)
Online: [ testvm101 ]

Full list of resources:

 Clone Set: virtual_ip-clone [virtual_ip] (unique)
     virtual_ip:0       (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started testvm101
     virtual_ip:1       (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started testvm101
 Clone Set: exim-clone [exim] (unique)
     exim:0     (systemd:exim): Started testvm101
     exim:1     (systemd:exim): Started testvm101

Failed actions:
    exim:0_monitor_30000 on testvm102 'not running' (7): call=150, status=complete, last-rc-change='Wed Jan 28 16:33:59 2015', queued=5ms, exec=15004ms
```

I'm running resource cleanup for the exim-resource to reset the fail-count:

```
[root@testvm101 ~]# pcs resource cleanup exim-clone
Resource: exim-clone successfully cleaned up
```

After a small amount of time, the status looks good (and actually also works good):

```
[root@testvm101 ~]# pcs status
...
Online: [ testvm101 testvm102 ]

Full list of resources:

 Clone Set: virtual_ip-clone [virtual_ip] (unique)
     virtual_ip:0       (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started testvm101
     virtual_ip:1       (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started testvm102
 Clone Set: exim-clone [exim] (unique)
     exim:0     (systemd:exim): Started testvm101
     exim:1     (systemd:exim): Started testvm102
```

Next time the monitor-action is performed, the check fails on the other node:

```
[root@testvm101 ~]# pcs status
...
Node testvm101 (1): standby (on-fail)
Online: [ testvm102 ]

Full list of resources:

 Clone Set: virtual_ip-clone [virtual_ip] (unique)
     virtual_ip:0       (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started testvm102
     virtual_ip:1       (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started testvm102
 Clone Set: exim-clone [exim] (unique)
     exim:0     (systemd:exim): Started testvm102
     exim:1     (systemd:exim): Started testvm102

Failed actions:
    exim:0_monitor_30000 on testvm101 'not running' (7): call=176, status=complete, last-rc-change='Wed Jan 28 16:37:10 2015', queued=0ms, exec=0ms
```

Maybe something I'm forgetting?

Appreciate the help